# Ensure that cable is not disconnected from my custom board

Tags: stm32, logic-gates, solid-state-relay, logic-level, electronic-load

I designed a custom board, the board includes stm32 that turns on a control voltage that operates SSR and the SSR goes to the load:
[image]
CTR comes from the GPIO of STM32.
in my custom board, there is some cable with a lot of signals that connect to board(analog,rs422,GND and voltage).
I want to ensure if the cable is disconnected in some cases, and if so the operation of the SSR will be turned off, only HW solution:
the STM32 turn on the relay if some voltage has detected, but in if the middle of operation the cable is disconnect, I want that relay turn off(without using in stm32)

If I add AND gate before the mosfet, and the inputs will be, stm32 ctrl and pullup to cable , it will be okay and works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Loop VCC through the cable**

Join two pins together on the cable.  Connect one terminal of the cable connector on your PCB to your VCC supply, and the other to the input labelled VCC on your diagram above.  If the cable is removed there will be no power to trigger the SSR and it'll turn off.  When the cable is plugged back in again, the SSR will re-engage. As a bonus the green LED will turn off when disconnected to indicate the problem.